# Not sure how to fix my sum formula in Excel

Tags: excel, sum, formula

[image]I have a large sum formula which doesn't seem to be working for some reason. The sum formula I am trying to fix is located in the first tab (SOW).Each row in the table in the third tab (Third-Party) has the option for a discount to be applied (column I). The formula which I am trying to fix would find the total discount amount. This calculation is Units (column F) x Unit Price (column G) and then the result multiplied by the discount percentage (column I). The total discount formula needs to sum each white row. There are 16 sections total (Production and Packaging are two different sections in the screenshot). Each section should have 20 rows (white rows). That's why the sum formula is so long at the moment. I hid the first couple of rows in the Production section only because it contains sensitive information.

The formula below is one attempt. I also tried replacing the "`+`" with a "`,`". I used the same exact formula on the third tab of this workbook. The only difference was that I didn't need to reference another tab and that column H was used instead of column I. I know sum is a very simple formula but need help since I am not sure what the problem is. I get the error message:

> missing a range reference or a defined name.

I don't understand why that is an issue since everything seems to be entered correctly.

```
=SUM((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F37*’THIRD-PARTY’!G37)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I37))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F38*’THIRD-PARTY’!G38)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I38))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F39*’THIRD-PARTY’!G39)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I39))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F40*’THIRD-PARTY’!G40)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I40))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F41*’THIRD-PARTY’!G41)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I41))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F42*’THIRD-PARTY’!G42)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I42))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F43*’THIRD-PARTY’!G43)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I43))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F44*’THIRD-PARTY’!G44)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I44))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F45*’THIRD-PARTY’!G45)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I45))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F46*’THIRD-PARTY’!G46)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I46))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F47*’THIRD-PARTY’!G47)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I47))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F48*’THIRD-PARTY’!G48)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I48))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F49*’THIRD-PARTY’!G49)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I49))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F50*’THIRD-PARTY’!G50)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I50))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F51*’THIRD-PARTY’!G51)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I51))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F52*’THIRD-PARTY’!G52)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I52))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F53*’THIRD-PARTY’!G53)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I53))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F54*’THIRD-PARTY’!G54)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I54))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F55*’THIRD-PARTY’!G55)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I55))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F56*’THIRD-PARTY’!G56)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I56))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F58*’THIRD-PARTY’!G58)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I58))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F59*’THIRD-PARTY’!G59)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I59))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F60*’THIRD-PARTY’!G60)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I60))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F61*’THIRD-PARTY’!G61)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I61))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F62*’THIRD-PARTY’!G62)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I62))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F63*’THIRD-PARTY’!G63)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I63))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F64*’THIRD-PARTY’!G64)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I64))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F65*’THIRD-PARTY’!G65)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I65))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F66*’THIRD-PARTY’!G66)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I66))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F67*’THIRD-PARTY’!G67)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I67))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F68*’THIRD-PARTY’!G68)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I68))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F69*’THIRD-PARTY’!G69)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I69))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F70*’THIRD-PARTY’!G70)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I70))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F71*’THIRD-PARTY’!G71)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I71))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F72*’THIRD-PARTY’!G72)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I72))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F73*’THIRD-PARTY’!G73)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I73))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F74*’THIRD-PARTY’!G74)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I74))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F75*’THIRD-PARTY’!G75)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I75))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F76*’THIRD-PARTY’!G76)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I76))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F77*’THIRD-PARTY’!G77)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I77))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F78*’THIRD-PARTY’!G78)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I78))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F79*’THIRD-PARTY’!G79)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I79))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F80*’THIRD-PARTY’!G80)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I80))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F81*’THIRD-PARTY’!G81)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I81))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F82*’THIRD-PARTY’!G82)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I82))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F83*’THIRD-PARTY’!G83)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I83))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F84*’THIRD-PARTY’!G84)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I84))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F85*’THIRD-PARTY’!G85)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I85))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F86*’THIRD-PARTY’!G86)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I86))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F87*’THIRD-PARTY’!G87)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I87))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F88*’THIRD-PARTY’!G88)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I88))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F89*’THIRD-PARTY’!G89)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I89))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F90*’THIRD-PARTY’!G90)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I90))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F91*’THIRD-PARTY’!G91)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I91))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F92*’THIRD-PARTY’!G92)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I92))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F93*’THIRD-PARTY’!G93)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I93))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F94*’THIRD-PARTY’!G94)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I94))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F95*’THIRD-PARTY’!G95)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I95))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F96*’THIRD-PARTY’!G96)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I96))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F97*’THIRD-PARTY’!G97)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I97))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F98*’THIRD-PARTY’!G98)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I98))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F100*’THIRD-PARTY’!G100)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I100))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F101*’THIRD-PARTY’!G101)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I101))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F102*’THIRD-PARTY’!G102)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I102))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F103*’THIRD-PARTY’!G103)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I103))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F104*’THIRD-PARTY’!G104)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I104))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F105*’THIRD-PARTY’!G105)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I105))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F106*’THIRD-PARTY’!G106)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I106))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F107*’THIRD-PARTY’!G107)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I107))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F108*’THIRD-PARTY’!G108)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I108))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F109*’THIRD-PARTY’!G109)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I109))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F110*’THIRD-PARTY’!G110)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I110))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F111*’THIRD-PARTY’!G111)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I111))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F112*’THIRD-PARTY’!G112)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I112))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F113*’THIRD-PARTY’!G113)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I113))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F114*’THIRD-PARTY’!G114)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I114))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F115*’THIRD-PARTY’!G115)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I115))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F116*’THIRD-PARTY’!G116)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I116))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F117*’THIRD-PARTY’!G117)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I117))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F118*’THIRD-PARTY’!G118)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I118))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F119*’THIRD-PARTY’!G119)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I119))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F121*’THIRD-PARTY’!G121)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I121))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F122*’THIRD-PARTY’!G122)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I122))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F123*’THIRD-PARTY’!G123)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I123))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F124*’THIRD-PARTY’!G124)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I124))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F125*’THIRD-PARTY’!G125)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I125))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F126*’THIRD-PARTY’!G126)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I126))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F127*’THIRD-PARTY’!G127)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I127))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F128*’THIRD-PARTY’!G128)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I128))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F129*’THIRD-PARTY’!G129)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I129))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F130*’THIRD-PARTY’!G130)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I130))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F131*’THIRD-PARTY’!G131)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I131))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F132*’THIRD-PARTY’!G132)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I132))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F133*’THIRD-PARTY’!G133)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I133))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F134*’THIRD-PARTY’!G134)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I134))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F135*’THIRD-PARTY’!G135)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I135))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F136*’THIRD-PARTY’!G136)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I136))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F137*’THIRD-PARTY’!G137)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I137))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F138*’THIRD-PARTY’!G138)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I138))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F139*’THIRD-PARTY’!G139)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I139))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F140*’THIRD-PARTY’!G140)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I140))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F142*’THIRD-PARTY’!G142)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I142))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F143*’THIRD-PARTY’!G143)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I143))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F144*’THIRD-PARTY’!G144)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I144))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F145*’THIRD-PARTY’!G145)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I145))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F146*’THIRD-PARTY’!G146)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I146))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F147*’THIRD-PARTY’!G147)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I147))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F148*’THIRD-PARTY’!G148)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I148))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F149*’THIRD-PARTY’!G149)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I149))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F150*’THIRD-PARTY’!G150)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I150))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F151*’THIRD-PARTY’!G151)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I151))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F152*’THIRD-PARTY’!G152)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I152))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F153*’THIRD-PARTY’!G153)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I153))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F154*’THIRD-PARTY’!G154)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I154))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F155*’THIRD-PARTY’!G155)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I155))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F156*’THIRD-PARTY’!G156)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I156))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F157*’THIRD-PARTY’!G157)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I157))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F158*’THIRD-PARTY’!G158)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I158))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F159*’THIRD-PARTY’!G159)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I159))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F160*’THIRD-PARTY’!G160)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I160))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F161*’THIRD-PARTY’!G161)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I161))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F163*’THIRD-PARTY’!G163)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I163))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F164*’THIRD-PARTY’!G164)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I164))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F165*’THIRD-PARTY’!G165)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I165))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F166*’THIRD-PARTY’!G166)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I166))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F167*’THIRD-PARTY’!G167)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I167))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F168*’THIRD-PARTY’!G168)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I168))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F169*’THIRD-PARTY’!G169)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I169))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F170*’THIRD-PARTY’!G170)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I170))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F171*’THIRD-PARTY’!G171)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I171))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F172*’THIRD-PARTY’!G172)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I172))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F173*’THIRD-PARTY’!G173)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I173))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F174*’THIRD-PARTY’!G174)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I174))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F175*’THIRD-PARTY’!G175)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I175))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F176*’THIRD-PARTY’!G176)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I176))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F177*’THIRD-PARTY’!G177)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I177))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F178*’THIRD-PARTY’!G178)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I178))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F179*’THIRD-PARTY’!G179)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I179))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F180*’THIRD-PARTY’!G180)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I180))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F181*’THIRD-PARTY’!G181)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I181))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F182*’THIRD-PARTY’!G182)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I182))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F184*’THIRD-PARTY’!G184)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I184))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F185*’THIRD-PARTY’!G185)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I185))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F186*’THIRD-PARTY’!G186)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I186))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F187*’THIRD-PARTY’!G187)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I187))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F188*’THIRD-PARTY’!G188)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I188))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F189*’THIRD-PARTY’!G189)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I189))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F190*’THIRD-PARTY’!G190)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I190))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F191*’THIRD-PARTY’!G191)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I191))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F192*’THIRD-PARTY’!G192)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I192))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F193*’THIRD-PARTY’!G193)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I193))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F194*’THIRD-PARTY’!G194)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I194))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F195*’THIRD-PARTY’!G195)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I195))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F196*’THIRD-PARTY’!G196)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I196))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F197*’THIRD-PARTY’!G197)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I197))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F198*’THIRD-PARTY’!G198)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I198))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F199*’THIRD-PARTY’!G199)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I199))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F200*’THIRD-PARTY’!G200)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I200))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F201*’THIRD-PARTY’!G201)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I201))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F202*’THIRD-PARTY’!G202)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I202))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F203*’THIRD-PARTY’!G203)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I203))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F205*’THIRD-PARTY’!G205)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I205))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F206*’THIRD-PARTY’!G206)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I206))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F207*’THIRD-PARTY’!G207)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I207))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F208*’THIRD-PARTY’!G208)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I208))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F209*’THIRD-PARTY’!G209)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I209))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F210*’THIRD-PARTY’!G210)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I210))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F211*’THIRD-PARTY’!G211)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I211))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F212*’THIRD-PARTY’!G212)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I212))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F213*’THIRD-PARTY’!G213)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I213))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F214*’THIRD-PARTY’!G214)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I214))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F215*’THIRD-PARTY’!G215)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I215))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F216*’THIRD-PARTY’!G216)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I216))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F217*’THIRD-PARTY’!G217)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I217))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F218*’THIRD-PARTY’!G218)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I218))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F219*’THIRD-PARTY’!G219)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I219))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F220*’THIRD-PARTY’!G220)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I220))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F221*’THIRD-PARTY’!G221)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I221))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F222*’THIRD-PARTY’!G222)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I222))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F223*’THIRD-PARTY’!G223)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I223))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F224*’THIRD-PARTY’!G224)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I224))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F226*’THIRD-PARTY’!G226)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I226))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F227*’THIRD-PARTY’!G227)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I227))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F228*’THIRD-PARTY’!G228)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I228))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F229*’THIRD-PARTY’!G229)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I229))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F230*’THIRD-PARTY’!G230)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I230))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F231*’THIRD-PARTY’!G231)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I231))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F232*’THIRD-PARTY’!G232)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I232))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F233*’THIRD-PARTY’!G233)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I233))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F234*’THIRD-PARTY’!G234)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I234))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F235*’THIRD-PARTY’!G235)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I235))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F236*’THIRD-PARTY’!G236)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I236))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F237*’THIRD-PARTY’!G237)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I237))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F238*’THIRD-PARTY’!G238)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I238))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F239*’THIRD-PARTY’!G239)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I239))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F240*’THIRD-PARTY’!G240)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I240))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F241*’THIRD-PARTY’!G241)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I241))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F242*’THIRD-PARTY’!G242)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I242))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F243*’THIRD-PARTY’!G243)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I243))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F244*’THIRD-PARTY’!G244)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I244))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F245*’THIRD-PARTY’!G245)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I245))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F247*’THIRD-PARTY’!G247)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I247))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F248*’THIRD-PARTY’!G248)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I248))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F249*’THIRD-PARTY’!G249)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I249))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F250*’THIRD-PARTY’!G250)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I250))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F251*’THIRD-PARTY’!G251)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I251))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F252*’THIRD-PARTY’!G252)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I252))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F253*’THIRD-PARTY’!G253)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I253))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F254*’THIRD-PARTY’!G254)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I254))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F255*’THIRD-PARTY’!G255)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I255))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F256*’THIRD-PARTY’!G256)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I256))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F257*’THIRD-PARTY’!G257)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I257))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F258*’THIRD-PARTY’!G258)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I258))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F259*’THIRD-PARTY’!G259)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I259))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F260*’THIRD-PARTY’!G260)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I260))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F261*’THIRD-PARTY’!G261)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I261))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F262*’THIRD-PARTY’!G262)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I262))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F263*’THIRD-PARTY’!G263)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I263))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F264*’THIRD-PARTY’!G264)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I264))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F265*’THIRD-PARTY’!G265)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I265))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F266*’THIRD-PARTY’!G266)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I266))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F268*’THIRD-PARTY’!G268)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I268))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F269*’THIRD-PARTY’!G269)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I269))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F270*’THIRD-PARTY’!G270)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I270))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F271*’THIRD-PARTY’!G271)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I271))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F272*’THIRD-PARTY’!G272)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I272))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F273*’THIRD-PARTY’!G273)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I273))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F274*’THIRD-PARTY’!G274)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I274))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F270*’THIRD-PARTY’!G270)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I270))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F271*’THIRD-PARTY’!G271)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I271))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F272*’THIRD-PARTY’!G272)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I272))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F273*’THIRD-PARTY’!G273)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I273))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F274*’THIRD-PARTY’!G274)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I274))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F275*’THIRD-PARTY’!G275)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I275))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F276*’THIRD-PARTY’!G276)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I276))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F277*’THIRD-PARTY’!G277)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I277))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F278*’THIRD-PARTY’!G278)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I278))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F279*’THIRD-PARTY’!G279)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I279))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F280*’THIRD-PARTY’!G280)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I280))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F281*’THIRD-PARTY’!G281)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I281))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F282*’THIRD-PARTY’!G282)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I282))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F283*’THIRD-PARTY’!G283)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I283))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F284*’THIRD-PARTY’!G284)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I284))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F285*’THIRD-PARTY’!G285)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I285))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F286*’THIRD-PARTY’!G286)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I286))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F287*’THIRD-PARTY’!G287)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I287))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F289*’THIRD-PARTY’!G289)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I289))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F290*’THIRD-PARTY’!G290)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I290))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F291*’THIRD-PARTY’!G291)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I291))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F292*’THIRD-PARTY’!G292)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I292))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F293*’THIRD-PARTY’!G293)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I293))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F294*’THIRD-PARTY’!G294)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I294))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F295*’THIRD-PARTY’!G295)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I295))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F296*’THIRD-PARTY’!G296)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I296))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F297*’THIRD-PARTY’!G297)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I297))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F298*’THIRD-PARTY’!G298)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I298))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F299*’THIRD-PARTY’!G299)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I299))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F300*’THIRD-PARTY’!G300)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I300))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F301*’THIRD-PARTY’!G301)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I301))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F302*’THIRD-PARTY’!G302)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I302))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F303*’THIRD-PARTY’!G303)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I303))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F304*’THIRD-PARTY’!G304)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I304))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F305*’THIRD-PARTY’!G305)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I305))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F306*’THIRD-PARTY’!G306)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I306))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F307*’THIRD-PARTY’!G307)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I307))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F308*’THIRD-PARTY’!G308)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I308))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F310*’THIRD-PARTY’!G310)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I310))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F311*’THIRD-PARTY’!G311)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I311))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F312*’THIRD-PARTY’!G312)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I312))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F313*’THIRD-PARTY’!G313)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I313))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F314*’THIRD-PARTY’!G314)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I314))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F315*’THIRD-PARTY’!G315)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I315))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F316*’THIRD-PARTY’!G316)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I316))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F317*’THIRD-PARTY’!G317)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I317))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F318*’THIRD-PARTY’!G318)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I318))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F319*’THIRD-PARTY’!G319)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I319))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F320*’THIRD-PARTY’!G320)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I320))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F321*’THIRD-PARTY’!G321)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I321))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F322*’THIRD-PARTY’!G322)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I322))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F323*’THIRD-PARTY’!G323)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I323))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F324*’THIRD-PARTY’!G324)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I324))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F325*’THIRD-PARTY’!G325)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I325))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F326*’THIRD-PARTY’!G326)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I326))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F327*’THIRD-PARTY’!G327)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I327))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F328*’THIRD-PARTY’!G328)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I328))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F329*’THIRD-PARTY’!G329)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I329))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F331*’THIRD-PARTY’!G331)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I331))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F332*’THIRD-PARTY’!G332)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I332))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F333*’THIRD-PARTY’!G333)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I333))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F334*’THIRD-PARTY’!G334)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I334))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F335*’THIRD-PARTY’!G335)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I335))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F336*’THIRD-PARTY’!G336)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I336))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F337*’THIRD-PARTY’!G337)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I337))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F338*’THIRD-PARTY’!G338)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I338))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F339*’THIRD-PARTY’!G339)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I339))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F340*’THIRD-PARTY’!G340)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I340))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F341*’THIRD-PARTY’!G341)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I341))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F342*’THIRD-PARTY’!G342)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I342))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F343*’THIRD-PARTY’!G343)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I343))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F344*’THIRD-PARTY’!G344)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I344))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F345*’THIRD-PARTY’!G345)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I345))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F346*’THIRD-PARTY’!G346)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I346))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F347*’THIRD-PARTY’!G347)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I347))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F348*’THIRD-PARTY’!G348)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I348))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F349*’THIRD-PARTY’!G349)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I349))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F350*’THIRD-PARTY’!G350)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I350))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F352*’THIRD-PARTY’!G352)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I352))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F353*’THIRD-PARTY’!G353)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I353))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F354*’THIRD-PARTY’!G354)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I354))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F355*’THIRD-PARTY’!G355)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I355))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F356*’THIRD-PARTY’!G356)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I356))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F357*’THIRD-PARTY’!G357)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I357))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F358*’THIRD-PARTY’!G358)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I358))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F359*’THIRD-PARTY’!G359)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I359))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F360*’THIRD-PARTY’!G360)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I360))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F361*’THIRD-PARTY’!G361)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I361))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F362*’THIRD-PARTY’!G362)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I362))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F363*’THIRD-PARTY’!G363)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I363))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F364*’THIRD-PARTY’!G364)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I364))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F365*’THIRD-PARTY’!G365)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I365))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F366*’THIRD-PARTY’!G366)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I366))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F367*’THIRD-PARTY’!G367)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I367))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F368*’THIRD-PARTY’!G368)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I368))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F369*’THIRD-PARTY’!G369)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I369))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F370*’THIRD-PARTY’!G370)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I370))+((‘THIRD-PARTY’!F371*’THIRD-PARTY’!G371)*(‘THIRD-PARTY’!I371))
```

Comment: You might need to break this into several parts. It could be too long for excel to parse.

Comment: You have `‘THIRD-PARTY’!F38’THIRD-PARTY’!G38` and many similar instances - that's definitely incorrect. There is most likely a simpler approach than this long formula.

Comment: And why are you using both SUM and +?

Comment: You need to rethink your approach.   There is almost certainly no need for such a large and horrible formula.  If you Post some sample data , we can advise on a better formula

Comment: @James McLeod - I thought that at first but doesn't make sense why a formula with the exact same length would work on the third tab but not the first one. No real reason except trying anything possible in regard to why using sum and +. I know you can just separate by commas. Would prefer to break this formula up but not sure the best way to do so.

Comment: I agree, @chris neilsen, just not sure what the better option is. Thanks for offering to help, will add a screenshot.

Comment: @BigBen. I'm very sorry, I must've copied the wrong version of the formula I have. That example you mentioned should be 'THIRD-PARTY'!F38*'THIRD-PARTY'!G38. This represents units multiplied by unit price.

Comment: Formula contents are limited to 8,192 characters.  Your formula is > 20,000 characters.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for letting me know @Ron Rosenfeld, is there a way to condense my current formula?

Comment: I'm sure there is.  See comments above.

Comment: you could use sumproduct(array1,array2,array3) which basically multiplies the values on each corresponding row of the arrays and then sums the result

Comment: Hi, @Cte6, thanks. This would work but my formula is too long? Is there a way to condense the formula?

Comment: =sumproduct(‘THIRD-PARTY’!F:F,’THIRD-PARTY’!G:G,‘THIRD-PARTY’!I:I)

Comment: I got the #NAME? error when I tried your formula, @cte6

Comment: @CTEAGUE212 cte6 's formula is correct.  It may be that copying from SO has put `’` quotes in your formula, when they should be `'` (ie single quotes) (this sometimes happen when copy / pasting to / from web pages)

Comment: Maybe it is because some rows in the table act as section headers and therefore the middle section of these rows are merged and centered, @cte6. One example of a header row is row 36; in this row, columns C:I are merged and centered.

Comment: @chris neilsen, a box opens which says "Cannot find 'PARTY'" when I retried using cte6's formula. I checked the formula after pasting and there's the correct amount of single quotes.

Comment: there was a problem with the quotation marks: =SUMPRODUCT('Third-Party'!F:F,'Third-Party'!G:G,'Third-Party'!I:I)  , besides that I just tested and worked fine

Comment: Thanks, @cte6! It's working now for me.

Comment: @ctec6 please add it as an answer